How can I select some field from this JSON (with SQL statement) in AWS IOT core?
I have got this data below from my device send to IoT core with MQTT (every second)
{
      "format": "json",
      "topic": "Moko_Anchor/gw/scanpub/40d63cb964e2",
      "timestamp": 1712222670798,
      "payload": [
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2024-04-04T16:24:16.772+07:00",
          "Format": "Gateway",
          "GatewayMAC": "40D63CB964E2"
        },
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2024-04-04T16:24:15.877+07:00",
          "Format": "BXP-ACC",
          "BLEMAC": "C00639178978",
          "RSSI": -79,
          "AdvType": "Legacy-adv",
          "TxPower": -4,
          "RSSI@0m": 0,
          "AdvInterval": 1000,
          "BattVoltage": 2799,
          "DataRate": 10,
          "Scale": "2g",
          "3-axisData": "3D80,F3C0,EE40"
        },
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2024-04-04T16:24:16.759+07:00",
          "Format": "BXP-ACC",
          "BLEMAC": "EA7A3411DE6C",
          "RSSI": -71,
          "AdvType": "Legacy-adv",
          "TxPower": -4,
          "RSSI@0m": 0,
          "AdvInterval": 1000,
          "BattVoltage": 2941,
          "DataRate": 10,
          "Scale": "2g",
          "3-axisData": "0F40,2DC0,D640"
        }
      ]

As you can see.. the number of array depend on Bluetooth device that my gateway can detect.
My problem is
--> I cannot send these JSON array to DynamoDB correctly (each field for each column). How can I edit it with SQL statement? right now I am using this..
sql statement
And DynamoDB can collect it all in ONE column like this.. put it in $unknown column
$unknown column
How can I make the right table match with my JSON array?
Thanks
--> I cannot send these JSON array to DynamoDB correctly (each field for each column). How can I edit it with SQL statement? right now I am using this..
sql statement
And DynamoDB can collect it all in ONE column like this.. put it in $unknown column
$unknown column
How can I make the right table match with my JSON array?
Thanks
